# Neo4J WHERE cause not strict?

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to filter connections where a GrossMargin is bigger than 8000000. For this I'm importing data like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///output.csv' AS row

MERGE (s:SalesOwner {name: row.Owner})
MERGE (c:Company {name: row.Company})
MERGE (l:Leader {name: row.Leader})
WITH s, c, toFloat(row.`Estimated Revenue`) AS revenue, toFloat(row.`Gross Margin I`) AS grossMargin

// Create relationships between SalesOwners and Companies, handling duplicates

MERGE (c)<-[d:DEAL_WITH]-(s)
ON CREATE SET d.GrossMargin = grossMargin, d.Revenue = revenue
ON MATCH SET d.GrossMargin = grossMargin, d.Revenue = revenue
MERGE (c)-[:HAS_LEADERSHIP]->(l)
```

Then I'm visualizing with:

```
MATCH (s:SalesOwner)-[d:DEAL_WITH]->(c:Company)
WHERE d.GrossMargin > 8000000
RETURN s, d, c
```

My CSV looks like this:

```
Owner,Company,Topic,Estimated Revenue,Gross Margin I,Leader
Name1,Company1,Topic1,6142488.51,6142488.51,Name2
Name1,Company1,Topic1,6142488.51,6142488.51,Name3
Name1,Company1,Topic1,6142488.51,6142488.51,Name4
Name1,Company1,Topic1,6142488.51,6142488.51,Name5
Name1,Company1,Topic1,6142488.51,6142488.51,Name6
Name1,Company1,Topic1,6142488.51,6142488.51,Name7
Name8,Company1,Company2,51600000.0,51600000.0,Name9
Name10,Company1,Company2,51600000.0,51600000.0,Name11
... etc
```

Yet, multiple connections that are SMALLER than 8000000 are still in the graph viz. How come?

Comment: By the way: `ON CREATE SET a=b ON MATCH SET a=b` can be simplified to just `SET a=b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable "Connect result nodes" in the settings dialog at the bottom left:

[image: Neo4j settings dialog: Graph Visualization]

If the setting is enabled (which it is by default), then all connections between two nodes will always be shown, even if not explicitly returned by your query.